# How to bring C++ complex numbers into C# application via SWIG?

Tags: c#, c++, swig

I found [here at 6.16](http://binf.gmu.edu/software/SWIG/SWIGPlus.html) example on user defined complex number class, yet I see no samples on how default C++ complex numbers are brought into other languages via SWIG, is there any sample, is there any requirement alike use of some `%include "std_complex.i"` inside my `.i` file?

Comment: Why don't you use `System.Numerics.Complex` ?

Answer (score 0):

The usual procedure is described in [section 8.4](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Library.html#Library_stl_cpp_library) of the [SWIG development documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Sections.html). As you can see from the table, it depends on the chosen language, to which parts of the C++ standard library the referring library modules provide access to, so far. SWIG support for the STL still continues to grow.

So the C++ `<complex>` library may or may not be supported for your target language. Concerning C#, there is no `std_complex.i` file inside the `swigwin-2.0.10\Lib\csharp` folder, hence no support.

Of course you could wrap it yourself *by hand*, but I guess that was not what your question aimed at. In the case of `<complex>` it also doesn't seem worth the effort, at least for me.